# Time is to go being so late

Tags: grammar

> Time is to go being so late. (from a dictionary) : Why says this? grammartically correct? I would just say "Time is late"

I wonder if I can say

1. "Time is going being so late" instead of the example sentence. or
2. "Time is going so late"
3. "Time is being so late" or
4. "Time is to get being so late" instead of "go" or
5. "Time is getting being so late" or
6. "Time is getting so late"

Maybe some of them are wrong?

Comment: In what dictionary did you find this? It doesn't seem at all idiomatic to me, and neither are any of your examples. We usually say "_It_ is getting late".

Comment: Time is to go being so late. Until late. : https://en.dict.naver.com/#/entry/enko/64e59de684d1448c89dc9ecdce98fa26

Comment: That wording "Time is to go being so late" is nonsense. Do not trust naver.com.

Comment: @Brandon Don't know how trustworthy that site is, but the translation seems like a really bad machine translation. It's definitely not good English. For what it's worth, Google Translate turns " 자 그럼" into "[Now then](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/now-then)", which is a set idiom, used as an interjection — it definitely can't be translated word-for-word as "time is to go being so late"

Comment: @anotherdave, The dictionary meant: It is getting late and see you later. And I wonder if the sentence "Time is to go being so late" is idiomatic and "Until late" is also idiomatic?

Comment: "Time is to go being so late" is not grammatically correct at all, so definitely not idiomatic. I assume it should mean something like "(Is that the time? I better go) it's getting late". (As Kate said). "Until later" (note the 'R') _could_ be said as a way of saying goodbye, but it would sound a little archaic. I wouldn't say it's idiomatic — 'See you later' would be a more natural way to say it, but it is casual.

Comment: _It's time to go_, not _time is._

Comment: We also say ***Time's getting on*** to draw attention to the passage of time - and hence by implication, ***It is now time to do something different***. But there's no real "focus" to this question, which really just seems to be prompted by the fact that there are some rubbishy websites out there.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know who wrote that phrase, but they are not able to speak English.  It is completely ungrammatical and virtually meaningless.

I put the Korean phrase into Google, and it does a much better job:

> It's too late to go. See you later.

That is at least grammatically correct.  I suspect the actual phrase is an idiomatic Korean expression which means "I should leave now because otherwise I will be late". An idiomatic English equivalent might be "It's getting late. I have to go. Bye."

The Korean expression makes an explict reference to time, but (if my interpretation is correct) the English equivalent does not talk about time, but uses the dummy pronoun "It's getting late".

Comment: Thx. The Korean means "It' late. I should go. See you later." in plain English.